# "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string" what is the reason for this exception

Tags: java, sql

I am running a set of SQL queries in Java to retrieve a, b, and c values. After that I want to do some operation with them and print the result to the user.

I am getting a "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string" when running the following code:

```
try {
    String sql1="SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Sick' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sick FROM `leave` WHERE `leave`.`EID`=? AND `leave`.`Month`=?";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(sql1); 
    String sql2="SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'annual' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS annual FROM `leave` WHERE `leave`.`EID`=? AND `leave`.`Date`=?";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
    int b= Integer.parseInt(sql2);
    String sql3="SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Half day' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Half_day FROM `leave` WHERE `leave.EID`=? AND `leave`.`Date`=?";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    int c= Integer.parseInt(sql3);

    if ((a+b+(c/2)) < 14) {
        int double_pay = 14 - (a+b+(c/2));
    }
    else {
        int double_pay = 0;
    }
    txt_double_pay.setText(double_pay+"");
} 
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Does anyone know the reason for this exception?

Comment: How are you trying to parse an int out of a whole SQL query string?

Answer (score 2):

the reason is

```
Integer.parseInt(sql3)
```

requires **sql3** to be a String holding data that can be parsed into an Integer..

you sql3 object is holding instead this:

```
sql3="SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Half day' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   AS Half_day FROM `leave` WHERE `leave.EID`=? AND `leave`.`Date`=?";
```

so java will never ever be able to get any number of that string....